# Result: Uncaught null on afterSave and beforeSave

Tags: parse-platform

As the title suggests, I'm encountering this error fairly often when triggering different cloud code hooks.

The code of the hooks themselves range from simple (5 loc) to more complex (100 loc).

The error output is just that "Result: Uncaught null", no stack trace no anything.

Has anyone encountered this issue? It's particularly damaging since it's preventing some saves from occurring.

Comment: not alone : https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-JS/issues/223

Answer (score 0):

I've found that "Result: Uncaught null" is often the result of not returning anything in your trigger. You don't necessarily need to return anything in an afterSave, but you do in the beforeSave or else everything will hang.